# Player twitching in cinemachine 2d

Tags: unity, 2d, cinemachine

Good afternoon, currently my player shakes when you move it to the left or right. I am using cinemachine 2d virtual cammera.

Here's my movement script:

```
using Microsoft.Cci;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed = 8f;
    private float jumpingPower = 5f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
    public bool  OnGround = true;
    public int JumpNum = 1;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        OnGround = false;
        Debug.Log("InAir false");
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        OnGround = true;
        Debug.Log("InAir True");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && JumpNum < 2)
        {
          rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
           JumpNum++;
            //double jump
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && !OnGround && JumpNum >= 2)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
            JumpNum = 1;
            //if jumpnum == 2, then reset jumpNum
        }

      //  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
       // {
            //rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
           // OnGround= false;
        //}
        //redundant

        Flip();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    //private bool IsGrounded()
   // {
       // return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
   // }
   //doesn't work
    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
}
```

I looked at similar questions such as: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/o84k7x/weird_shaking_with_player_controllercinemachine/

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441202/picked-up-object-is-shaking-when-moving#:~:text=The%20ways%20around%20this%20all%20revolve%20around%20either,the%20same%20time%20%28moving%20your%20interaction%20to%20Update%29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441202/picked-up-object-is-shaking-when-moving#:%7E:text=The%20ways%20around%20this%20all%20revolve%20around%20either,the%20same%20time%20%28moving%20your%20interaction%20to%20Update%29).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158051/twitching-objects-in-unity-during-camera-movement-in-2d

But the answers to those questions did not help me.

Is there any way to fix the player's shaking when moving it left or right?

Comment: Do you mean with shaking that you are calling `Flip()` every single Update?

Comment: Yea, I tried changing the ```void Update()``` to ```void LateUpdate()``` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: In most cases you should not modify the velocity directly, as this can result in unrealistic behaviour - use AddForce instead. Do not set the velocity of an object every physics step, this will lead to unrealistic physics simulation.

Comment: Doing the AddForce doesn't solve the issue, maybe it's when the sprite flips from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Cci;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    public float speed = 1f;
    private float jumpingPower = 5f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
    public bool  OnGround = true;
    public int JumpNum = 1;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        OnGround = false;
        Debug.Log("InAir false");
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        OnGround = true;
        Debug.Log("InAir True");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && JumpNum < 2)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpingPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
          //rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
           JumpNum++;
            //double jump
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && !OnGround && JumpNum >= 2)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpingPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            JumpNum = 1;
            //if jumpnum == 2, then reset jumpNum
        }

      //  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
       // {
            //rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
           // OnGround= false;
        //}
        //redundant

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * speed);
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontal * speed, 0f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        Flip();
    }

    //private bool IsGrounded()
   // {
       // return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
   // }
   //doesn't work
    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
}
```

I figured it out. Thank you so much for the help!